# Various + (Uncountable noun) is acceptable?

Tags: adjectives

When proofreading a paper, I saw a sentence as follows:

> SSDs consist of *various hardware* (e.b., NAND flash, DRAM, CPU) and complicated software (e.g., flash translation layer).

Sometimes I also carelessly use **various** to modify uncountable nouns such as **hardware** in this example, but I am not sure whether this usage is acceptable in an official academic paper.

Comment: I think this question also goes for other adjectives such as **multiple** and **several**.

Comment: Various types of hardware. No, ***various hardware*** is not acceptable.

Comment: @Lambie Why not? An answer with some explanation would be good.

Comment: You already know the rule. Various does not go with uncountable nouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that various can only modify a plural noun (there must have been more than one possibility) So a correct phrase would be "various kinds/types/sorts of hardware.

It s interesting that this rule applies even though hardware describes many different objects. However, it is not a plural noun because it describes just one class of objects.

And indeed the rule would also apply to multiple/several/many...